# Cannot comment single post: comment box not displayed on click

Tags: support, comments, error-message

In this post [SO:4532241](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532241/), I can click 'add comment' on any post, and a comment box will be displayed, as usual - **except** on a single post which is currently rendered at the bottom, which is [SO:4532853](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532241/4532853#4532853)

I've noticed, the first time I click on the 'add comment', it gets ignored - the second time I click, the 'add comment' link disappears - and there is no 'comment-form' rendered. Funnily, if I select that area of the page and inspect 'View Selection Source' after the problem happens, I see:

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="comment-form"><form id="add-comment-4532853"><table><tbody><tr><td><textarea name="comment" cols="68" rows="3"></textarea></td><td><input value="Add Comment" type="submit"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><span class="text-counter"></span><span class="form-error"></span></td></tr></tbody></table></form></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

... which, I guess, means that as far as the JS engine goes, request for comment box got through, and the response HTML to that did get generated - it just doesn't display.

I use `Firefox` 3.6.13 with latest `NoScript` on `Ubuntu` 10.04; in this case I allowed all of the webservers for that particular page in `NoScript`, and that didn't seem to make a difference. I use this on a netbook though - so maybe there's some sort of a conflict of the layout with the screen display geometry??

Anyways - does anyone have any idea why this happens(ed)?

Cheers!

**EDIT**: Here is a bit of a 'hack' log:

on load of page, Firebug reports errors:

```
gauth is not defined
[Break on this error] <script type="text/javascript"...th('http://stackauth.com');</script> 

styleCode is not defined
[Break on this error] styleCode();
```

By clicking through the HTML tree in Firebug, the approximate area of this post has the Xpath:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table
```

in which I manually added some of the names (by using `$x("xpath")` syntax in Firebug console):

```
/html/body/div[4]([div.container])/div[2]([[div#content]])/div[2]([div#mainbar])/div[2]([div#answers])/div[4]([div#answer-4532853.answer])/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table([table.fw])
```

Here is the XPath and the behaviour of the 'add comment' button - and the corresponding comment form - upon click:

```
add-comment link: 
//*[@id="comments-link-4532853"]
first OK in HTML in Firebug - after click; greyed out

actual box?:
//*[@id="comments-4532853"]
first greyed out in HTML in Firebug - after click; still greyed out
```

Then in firebug HTML tree, I selected

```
<div class="comments" id="comments-4532853 dno">
```

... and changed manually the id to id="comments-4532853". Then the box appears - however, the element in the Firebug HTML tree is still greyed out..

Finally, added text, and clicked on Add Comment - and my comment instead appeared in the URL, as in `http:...-readlink?comment=Hi+%...` - and of course, the link didn't get posted..

Looks like some javascriptery mess on my Firefox, but I'm still at loss at what it could be..

Comment: norepro (Chrome 8).

Comment: Hi @KennyTM, thanks for your comment! Must be something related to Firefox, then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, here's how:

- First, close all yer tabs in Firefox
- In Firefox, go to Tools / Clear Recent History

  - Time range to clear: Everything
  - Check box only on Cookies and Cache
  - click 'Clear Now'
- go to http://stackoverflow.com

  - (noticed here, that `NoScript` started reporting 'http://stackauth.com' as not allowed, allowed it)
- Login in SO (for me, with OpenID)
- Go to post
- Click 'add comment'
- It works ! :)

Hope this helps,
Cheers!